# My account Edit Billing address doesn't save changes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, account

I have a standard Woocommerc account. When I go to Edit Billing Address and edit some field and save it to my-account/edit-address/, the information remains the same when I reboot. Although if I enter a new value and save it, then when my-account/edit-address/billing/ is rebooted, this value will be saved. It disappears when you go to another page. What could be the problem?

```js
<?php
/**
 * Edit address form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-address.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 7.0.1
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$page_title = ( 'billing' === $load_address ) ? esc_html__( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ) : esc_html__( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_address_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( ! $load_address ) : ?>
    <?php wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-address.php' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>

    <form method="post">

        <h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title, $load_address ); ?></h3><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-address-fields">
            <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

            <div class="woocommerce-address-fields__field-wrapper">
                <?php
                foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {
                    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, wc_get_post_data_by_key( $key, $field['value'] ) );
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="button<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>" name="save_address" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address', 'woocommerce-edit-address-nonce' ); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
            </p>
        </div>

    </form>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_address_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: Nobody can really guess what the problem is. If you added custom code, disable/comment your code and check if the issue is still there… Then, if you haven't made changes to the related template, first make a database backup, and try to switch to another theme (like WooCommerce storefront) and see if the problem remains. If it remains, try to disable all plugins except WooCommerce and re-enable them one by one, testing each time in between... All that process will allow you to find what is making trouble.